# Возможно ли создать массив с HTMLelement ключем и строкой в значении?

Tags: javascript

По типу:

```
let arr = [
div.Something: 5 2
]
```

Comment: Скорее всего да, только вот из описания не понятно, что вы хотите получить

Comment: Нет. У массива в JS ключи по определению числа. Но, возможно, на самом деле тебе нужен Map. Но лучше бы описать реальную задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Для реализации того что Вы описали в задаче лучше всего использовать `Map`.

Например, если в HTML у нас есть такой unorder list:

```
<ul>
  <li class="list"></li>
  <li class="list"></li>
  <li class="list"></li>
</ul>
```

В JS мы создаем новый `Map`, в отличии от `Array`, в котором ключи это всегда индексы элемента в массиве, или `Object` в котором ключи это всегда строки.

В `Map` ключами может быть любая сущность, в том числе и другой объект. `HTMLElement` это как раз тоже объект.

```js
const map = new Map();

const lists = document.getElementsByClassName("list");

for (const list of lists) {
    map.set(list, [1, 2]);
}

console.log(map.get(lists[0]));
```

```js
const map = new Map();

const lists = document.getElementsByClassName("list");

for (const list of lists) {
    map.set(list, [1, 2]);
}

console.log(map.get(lists[0]));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list"></li>
  <li class="list"></li>
  <li class="list"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: _в отличии от Array, в котором ключи это всегда индексы элемента в массиве_ - не всегда. ты спокойно можешь добавить в массив строковый ключ, который не будет являться индексом. Кроме чисел и строк, есть еще Symbol, который также может являться ключом

Comment: Разве число может быть ключем объекта? В целом я согласен с комментарием, однако это было намеренное допущение, что бы подчеркнуть зачем в решении этой задачи использовать именно Map.

Comment: Там сложно работает. Все ключи в объекте приводятся к строке либо Symbol, однако ключи которые могут быть индексами массива `0-2^32-1` хранятся специальным образом